# Need to add a fade effect between two backgrounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, background

I want to add a fade effect for this jquery background change code

```
 var images = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg'];
 var i = 0;

 setInterval(function(){
    $('body').css('background-image', function() {
            if (i >= images.length) {
                i=0;
            }
            return 'url(' + images[i++] + ')'; 
        });
 }, 5000);
```

Comment: using jquery i don't think it is possible. try css3 animation http://www.mightymeta.co.uk/fading-button-background-images-with-css3-transitions/

Answer (score 0):

The result you want cannot be done with your current approach, and I'm not pretty sure if it could be done with `CSS` `animations`. But you could do it if you you use two elements that fit the body, add the backgrounds to them and fade them accordingly.